# How button view in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I meet some question about the vue to learn.

My problem is component problem.

I think the project can be run.

But the second button can not be seen.

so i meet a big Error.
it how can run

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vue 101</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <awesome-button></awesome-button>
    <hr>
    <music-button></music-button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <script>
      Vue.component('awesome-button', {
        template: `<button @click="clickHandler">Click me for some awesomeness</button>`,
        methods: {
            clickHandler() {
            alert('YAAAS ');
            }
        }
        });
        Vue.component('mucic-button',{
            template:`<button @click="clickMusic">Click me for some music</button>`,
            methods:{
            clickMusic() {
                alert('halou');
            }
            }
        });
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am a learner,i think my project have no problem
when i see , the second button cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the component name:

It should be `music-button`, you wrote `mucic-button`.